# plotting all the points in x-y graph with the same time coordinate

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide, matlab-deployment

How do I mark or plot all the points in the x and y graph that have the same t-coordinate? 
I've gotten `[t, P]` with help of `ode45` and `ode20` start positions.The time is shown by `t` and `P` is the matrix that contains all the `x-` and `y-`coordinates which are our answers.

So I plotted the answer and I got several curves.
Now I want to mark or plot all the points that have the same time.

How do I do that?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have several curves (x, y, t) and would like to choose a certain t = T, and plot all the (x, y) for t = T. I haven't used the ode functions in some time, but I assume you have N sets of {t, P} which I'll denote using t{i} and P{i}

If all your (x, y, t) curves are sampled at T, then you can do something like this

```
close all
for k = 1:N
    correctTimeIndex = find(t{k} == T);
    plot(P{k}(correctTimeIndex, :); % assuming two columns for x, y
    hold all
end
```

If your (x, y, t) curves are not sampled at the correct value of T, then you'll need to interpolate using `interp1` to get the right values for x and y.